# What package do I install to enable fork in Cygwin? It says "error command line: unknown option fork"

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, cygwin, fork

I am new to cygwin. I just installed v1.7.25(0.270/5/3) on my win7 machine. When I invoke mongod with

```
--fork [mongod --configsvr --dbpath cfg2 --port 26052  --logpath log.cfg2 --logappend]
```

it say :

> "error command line: unknown option fork".

What I understand is that `--fork` is a linux or unix command not necessarily a mongod command. So how to make it work in cygwin on windows? On the other hand, is the problem happening because windows installation of mongod cannot do `--fork`? I am confused here, pls help!!!

Comment: Why do you need `fork` to work on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Fork as a configuration option is **not supported** by the windows version of mongodb. So if you downloaded the windows binary, it will not be able to use the `--fork` option to run in the background of your shell. If you run `mongod --help`, the `--fork` option shouldn't appear. If you want, you can still start `mongod` from cygwin, but you'll need to use the windows command line to do it.

If your ultimate goal is to get you database process running in the background, in Windows the way to do this is to set up mongodb as a service: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service

Comment: Though cygwin can do fork, but so super slowly that it isn't even worth mentioning

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to go that route, but not with a pre-built windows binary. Either way it is not recommended :)